# CodeIgniter Login function form not working

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter, bcrypt

I have sum up this is my code for my login function, I'm using CodeIgniter framework. I am trying to make users login with their email and password. I'm trying to use bcrypt hash password to login but I must be doing something wrong in my coding because it is not logging and it keeps showing invalid.

```
public function login()
{

    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == 1 
        && in_array($this->session->userdata('user_type'), ['Admin', 'Member']) {
            redirect('dashboard', 'location');
    }

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');


    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
        $this->login_page();
    } else {
        $this->csrf_token_check();

        $username = ($this->input->post('username', true));
        $password = ($this->input->post('password', true));
          
        $table = 'users';

        if($this->config->item('master_password') != '') {
            if ($_POST['password']) {
                $where['where'] = array('email' => $username); //master password
            } else {
                $where['where'] = array('email' => $username, 'password' => $password);
            }
        } else {
            $where['where'] = array('email' => $username, 'password' => $password);
        }


        $info = $this->basic->get_data($table, $where, $select = '', $join = '', $limit = '', $start = '', $order_by = '', $group_by = '', $num_rows = 1);

        $count = $info['extra_index']['num_rows'];

        if ($count == 0) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('login_msg', $this->lang->line("invalid email or password"));
            redirect(uri_string());
        } else {
            $username = $info[0]['name'];

            if ($logo=="") {
                $logo=base_url("assets/img/avatar/avatar-1.png");
            } else {
                $logo=base_url().'member/'.$logo;
            }

            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', 1);
            $this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);

            $this->basic->insert_data('user_login_info',$login_info_insert_data);

            $this->basic->update_data("users",array("id"=>$user_id),array("last_login_at"=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),'last_login_ip'=>$login_ip)); if(function_exists('fb_app_set'))fb_app_set();

            if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == 1 
                && in_array($this->session->userdata('user_type'), ['Admin', 'Member']) {
                redirect('dashboard', 'location');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is specific to CI3, as you have not mentioned the version.

First, I think it's weird you're using `$username` for `email` field in DB. you can correct your naming conventions.

I think this piece of code must be giving you problems

```php
if($this->config->item('master_password') != '')
            {
                if(($_POST['password']))
                $where['where'] = array('email' => $username); //master password
                else $where['where'] = array('email' => $username, 'password' => $password);
            }
            else $where['where'] = array('email' => $username, 'password' => $password);
```

if you're using the above `$where` directly in CI as `$this->db->where($where)`, Your code should be

```php
if($this->config->item('master_password') != '')
            {
                if(($_POST['password']))
                $where = array('email' => $username); //master password
                else $where = array('email' => $username, 'password' => $password);
            }
            else $where = array('email' => $username, 'password' => $password);
```

Notice, I removed `where` key from the `$where` array.

Also, if you're using bcrypt to store password in db, you have to fetch the row first and then compare the password like this:

```php
    $where = array('email' => $username);
    $info = $this->basic->get_data($table, $where, $select = '', $join = '', $limit = '', $start = '', $order_by = '', $group_by = '', $num_rows = 1);

    if ($this->bcrypt->check_password($password, $info[0]['password'])) {
        //We're good, login to the system
    } else {
        //Wrong password
    }
```

I think, your other code, like `$this->basic->get_data` function should also be reviewed. To debug, try putting `var_dump($info[0]);` after this function, you'll know if you have a the row or not.

Also, you can use `$str = $this->db->last_query();` to print out the last query run.

Comment: thanks for this, i am trying this and let you know and also when i mention bcrypt it says function undefined

Comment: i tried this, it is loggin in even with incorrect password @jazeabby

Comment: for bcrypt , try using this:

`if( password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT) == $info[0]['password']){
}`

Comment: i made some change,i added md5 

" $password = md5($this->input->post('password', true));
          
            $table = 'users';

            if($this->config->item('master_password') != '')
            {
                if(md5($_POST['password']))
                $where['where'] = array('email' => $username); //master password
                else $where['where'] = array('email' => $username, 'password' => $password);
            }
            else $where['where'] = array('email' => $username, 'password' => $password);"

 its working but its now only fetching md5,i need bcrypt

Comment: Can you share an example string, how password is stored in database?
if it's something like
`$2y$12$QjSH496pcT5CEbzjD/vtVeH03tfHKFy36d4J0Ltp3lRtee9HDxY3K`, the above should work

Comment: yes its this "$2y$10$TO.zuf9oy2cjE6ZredA6I.P.4iD9BcRbguJmOyWXOwNQl4pnYg7SO" but with my md5 code "64e1b8d34f425d19e1ee2ea7236d3028" login starts working correctly

Comment: try `password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT)`

Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: i already tried this before it also didnt worked @jazeabby

Comment: what does `password_hash($password)` returns?? did you try to var_dump the `password_hash($password)` ? This is the native PHP function, it should compare the same values

Comment: @jazeabby Not same values but rather same algorithm. It is suppose to always be different values.

Comment: @ArmeenMoon what's the password column length in db? try increasing it to 128, if less?

Comment: when i make "password_hash($password)" instead of md5 my login system doesnt work like it doesnt throw any error but weird thing is it logs in even if i enter invalid password

Comment: @jazeabby my password length is 255 var

Comment: @jazeabby should i drop my project? so you can check it out

Comment: @ArmeenMoon I can look into it, if you want, if you have github, find me on github, with same username

Comment: @jazeabby https://github.com/armeenmoon/Ci_login check this, i dropped my app plus sql, the password is "admin@admin.com"

Comment: please read this concerning md5 for password hashing: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/52463

Comment: @Vickel yes i have read that, thats my issue thats why i want to avoid using md5 i am trying to get rid of it, if i remove md5 it stops working

Comment: I'd also recommend to use [Codeigniter ion-auth](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth) library for logins, it's easy to implement and secure

Comment: @Vickel i would have tried it thanks for it, but i cant change my whole login its linked with my project i have to solve that part of code

Comment: well, with that library you have a lot of source code to get inspired from, don't forget salt (and eventually pepper)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226936/discussion-between-armeen-moon-and-vickel).